# Enforce authentification (passcode, Touch ID, Face ID) for viewing saved passwords on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, password

I have surprisingly realized that I can view all my (Safari) saved passwords on my iPhone under iOS 14.4 without having to type my passcode (again). This is problematic as for a regular user, it would be easy for somebody to steal all their saved passwords by just borrowing their phone to "make a call".

On macOS, if I want to view the saved passwords in Safari preferences, I have to type again my Mac password. Same for Chrome.

Is there a way to enforce this on iOS?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: What is the iOS path for viewing Safari saved passwords?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Settings -> Passwords.

Comment: Thanks. When I go to Settings > Passwords, my iPhone SE (iOS 14.4.1) brings up an authentication dialog requiring Touch ID authentication. Perhaps your phone, in Settings > Touch ID & Passcode, has "Require Passcode" set differently; mine says "Immediately."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Oops, I remember having to reset the settings of my phone (as recommended by Apple) because after the upgrade the battery was draining too fast (1% per 20 seconds), so currently Passcode and Touch ID are deactivated. I have been using the phone over the last days without realizing that. Thanks to your comment, I have checked the settings and enable them, now everything is working as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 14, you can access saved passwords in Settings > Password.

If the iPhone has a Passcode and/or Touch ID enabled, access to passwords will require authentication, and Settings > Touch ID & Passcode will display "Require Passcode" as "immediately."

Comment: You’re very welcome!